# Using OpenCV with NDK in Android app development

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am testing `facedetection` program at `Android` with `NDK`. I followed all discussions [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html). I copied all `OpenCV's` library files inside `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` into my `project libs folder`. Then my Android.mk is updated as

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES  :=  on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES   :=  off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE         :=  STATIC
include C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then I go to command window and type

```
C:\facedetection\jni\include>javah -classpath ../../bin/classes;C:
\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar -o DetectionBas
edTracker_jni.h org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity
Error: Class org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase could not be found.
```

Then the error is `Class org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase could not be found`.
What could be the reason for that error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are providing wrong `\` slash. You need to use this `/` slash instead.

Please change your below line

```
include C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk
```

to

```
include C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Comment: I have changed, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @batuman, ok, for what reason you are using this `javah -classpath` command ?

Comment: It is to locate the location of the class. The discussion can be seen here http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html

Comment: Do you want to build .so file ?

Comment: If you were able to build .so file successfully then you dont need that command. Just refresh your project from project/package explorer and run it as Android Application.---> Done.

Comment: Yes you are right. I do ndk-build and no need that command. Thanks. Can please answer?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. At present I am doing an Android app where I am too using OpenCV Library, that's why I know this. :)